# Extracting values from <select> and putting them into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, select

Surely, this shouldn't be so hard?

I have a `<select>`, which has, of course, `<options>`.  These `options` are **always** in number format, because they are dynamically added to the list by the user.

I then need to get all of these options from the list, put them an array and then perform logic on the array.  I've tried searching around, but everything relates to jquery or php - and I'm using plain old HTML and JavaScript.

The `select` is in a scrolling-box format:

```
<select id="selectBox" name="select" size="15" style="width:190px;">  
<!-- <options> are added via javascript -->     
</select>
```

Currently, I'm using this JavaScript to get the elements, but it's not working:

```
//Calculate all numbers
        var x=[];
    function calculate()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++)
        {
            x[i]=selectbox.options[i].value;
            alert(x[i]);
        }

    }
```

`Calculate()` is called by a button.  Something is going terribly wrong, and I can't work it out.  `selectbox` is previously defined as `var selectbox = document.getElementById("selectBox");` and I know this works.

The alert is only being called so I can try to debug the thing...

I'm using the figure of `999` because I can't work out how to get a number of how many elements are in the `<select>` (because it is in scrolling-box format).
The solution **must** be **javascript**, and the listbox **must** be in that scrolling-box format.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit** -- Okay, more coding to help this.

```
<form id="aggregateForm">
    <input id="inputNum" value="" type="text"><input id="addnum" value="Add" onclick="add();" type="button">
    <br>
    <select id="selectBox" name="select" size="15" style="width:190px;">  

    </select>
    <br>
    <input id="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();" type="button"><input id="reset" value="Reset" onclick="reset();" type="button">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectbox = document.getElementById("selectBox");

    function add()
    {
    //Function to add a new number to the list of digits
    //Parses an integer to ensure everything works okay
    if(IsNumeric(document.getElementById("inputNum").value) == true)
    {
        selectbox.options[selectbox.options.length] = new Option(document.getElementById("inputNum").value, document.getElementById("inputNum").value);
        inputNum.focus();
    }
    else if(IsNumeric(document.getElementById("inputNum").value) == false)
    {
        alert("I'm sorry, but you have entered an invalid number. Please enter a number into the input box.");
        inputNum.focus();
    }
    }

    //Calculate all numbers
    var x=[];
    function calculate()
    {
    for (var i = 0; i <selectbox.options.length; i++)
        {
    x[i]=selectbox.options[i].value;
    alert(x[i]);
        }


    }

    //IsNumeric function coding taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric, code by Joel Coehoorn
    function IsNumeric(input)
    {
        return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery? And assigning to alert is a typo right? `alert=(x[i]);`

Comment: I **have** to use javascript (long story), sorry.  And why is `alert` wrong?

Comment: jQuery *is* Javascript. And `alert(x[i])` looks more like what you want. Or maybe `console.log(x)` after the loop.

Comment: *Ohhh*, fixing the alert now..Maybe it *was* working...? And I have to do all the programming myself, in pure Javascript.

Comment: No, alert still doesn't work - must be my coding.

Comment: selectbox.options.length will give you the number of options...

Comment: Ok, more code added - sorry it's a bit long, but this should help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that calculate is the ID of the element too. And oddly enough it believes that calculate is that DOM object not you function: [**proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGxzs/). I changed the function name to `calculates`.

I only found out last week that you can reference your elements with IDs with said IDs.

```
<div id="really">Yep for some reason</div>
```

... later in javascript

```
// no document.getElementById, just
// let me be very clear, THIS IS WRONG TO USE VERY BAD SO EVERYONE CAN KNOW NOT TO USE THIS
// but it does work this way so be aware
really.innerHTML = "I guess he was right.";
```

Comment: OMG. That worked! Thanks so much! :D I'll keep that in mind...thanks so much, that worked in an instant!

Comment: Nooo!!! **Don't use IDs as global variables!!** That is a really bad (non-standard) feature introduced by IE and copied by others to be compatible. **Please don't use it or recommend its use**.

Comment: @RobG, no where did I ever say that. Not once.

Comment: Right were you wrote `"// no document.getElementById, just
really.innerHTML = "I guess he was right.";`.

Comment: @RobG, because that's how it works by default. That needs to be understood.

Comment: That **isn't** how it works by default at all, try it in Firefox with an HTML 4 strict DOCTYPE. If it needs to be understood, then you should explain it (you didn't). If you do then I'll remove the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjy54/)

```
var selectbox = document.getElementById("selectBox");

var x = [];

function calculate()
{
    for (var i = 0; i <selectbox.options.length; i++)
    {
        x[i]=selectbox.options[i].value;
        alert(x[i]);
    }

}
calculate();
```

This will alert EVERY option element in the select.

Comment: Brian, that didn't work...I am calling calculate() from a button way above the script, so this should work..but it doesn't.

Comment: do you get any errors? what happens? We might need to see more of the code.

Comment: Can you also alert(selectbox) to make sure that it really exists?

Comment: No, the `<select>` exists all right; it's ID is `selectBox` and I'm using the variable `var selectbox = document.getElementById("selectBox")`

Comment: Just a comment: the script on this answer run well on jsFiddle, but only after removing "=" from "alert=(x[i]);".